# How could I migrate HTML5 local storage into mediaWiki

Tags: javascript, html, mediawiki, local-storage

I have explored the web but could not find how the data in the local storage of HTML5 be shown as a content in my Wiki? My aim is that if I have to put any data in the local storage of my HTML5 code, it should be shown to my Wiki page. How could I relate these two (HTML5/JS and MediaWiki)? My HTML 5 code is given as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> HTML5 localStorage (name/value item pairs) demo </title> 

      <style>

          td, th {
              font-family: monospace;
              padding: 4px;
              background-color: #ccc;
          }
          #hoge {
              border: 1px dotted blue;
              padding: 6px;
              background-color: #ccc;
              margin-right: 50%;
         }
         #items_table {
              border: 1px dotted blue;
              padding: 6px;
              margin-top: 12px;
              margin-right: 50%;
         }
         #items_table h2 {
             font-size: 18px;
             margin-top: 0px;
             font-family: sans-serif;
         }
         label {
             vertical-align: top;
         }
        </style>

     </head>

  <body onload="doShowAll()" >

  <h1> HTML5 localStorage (name/value item pairs) demo</h1>

  <form name=editor>

    <div id="hoge">

     <p>

     <label> Value: <textarea name=data cols=41 rows=10></textarea></label>

     </p>

     <p>

      <label>Name: <input name=name></label>
      <input type=button value="getItem()" onclick="doGetItem()">
      <input type=button value="setItem()" onclick="doSetItem()">
      <input type=button value="removeItem()" onclick="doRemoveItem()">
     </p>
   </div>

   <div id="items_table">

     <h2>Items</h2>

     <table id=pairs></table>
     <p>

     <label><input type=button value="clear()" onclick="doClear()"> <i>* clear() removes all items</i></label>
     </p>
   </div>


   <script>

     function doSetItem() {
       var name = document.forms.editor.name.value;
       var data = document.forms.editor.data.value;
       localStorage.setItem(name, data);
       doShowAll();
     }

     function doGetItem() {
       var name = document.forms.editor.name.value;
       document.forms.editor.data.value = localStorage.getItem(name);
       doShowAll();
     }

     function doRemoveItem() {
       var name = document.forms.editor.name.value;
       document.forms.editor.data.value = localStorage.removeItem(name);
       doShowAll();
     }

     function doClear() {
       localStorage.clear();
       doShowAll();
     }

     function doShowAll() {
       var key = "";
       var pairs = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n";
       var i=0;
       for (i=0; i<=localStorage.length-1; i++) {
         key = localStorage.key(i);
         pairs += "<tr><td>"+key+"</td>\n<td>"+localStorage.getItem(key)+"</td></tr>\n";
       }
       if (pairs == "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n") {
         pairs += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
       }
       document.getElementById('pairs').innerHTML = pairs;
     }

   </script>

  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

My Wiki URL is: http://localhost:8888/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

My question is how the data input into the text area of the HTML5 code could be shown into my Wiki page? Where and how should I relate this wiki URL with the HTML5/JS script for local storage?

Comment: The `localhost` URL is only accessible on the computer that has the server installed. It isn't possible for others here to access your computer that way.

Comment: I know it... Now I only want to do it in my local machine... I need to have some tips how the data input to Html 5 local storage be migrated to wiki

Comment: @Partha mukherjee I'm not sure what your comment is trying to say, but at this point I am worried you are attempting use Stackoverflow as your personal outsourcing firm.  Stackoverflow is a community about learning, you need to start learning at a much more basic level I think because this project seems far more complex than skills at this moment are going to allow.  Also please try and accept some answers to your previous questions or you are going to meet much more resistance to your questions here.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to read this data in server side code?

Answer (score 6):

You're going to need a fair amount of programming skills to go about this in the correct manner.  No one here is going to program it for you.  Here is the best resource there is available.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

The fact that you put a localhost url in your post obviously shows that you have quite a bit to learn about web development in general.  I wish you luck.

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're asking... but here goes nothing...

Step 1) Read the data from your local storage (use Caimen's link for help).

Step 2) Use JavaScript to group it into JSON, XML, comma delimited string, etc...

Step 3) POST to the server (AJAX or old fashioned POST)

Step 4) Use a server-side language (assuming PHP) to parse the POST and insert it into the mediaWiki DB

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that https://www.odesk.com/ might be more suitable for this request than StackOverflow. It sounds like you're asking for someone to get quite involved in your task and guide you through the process.

This kind of personal attention generally isn't free, and it is unlikely someone will want to devote a decent amount of time towards it. However if you pay someone, on say oDesk, you're likely to get a working solution for your specific problem.

However if you can funnel your question down to a key point, we may be able to help with that...

Comment: I need to have some tips how the data input to Html 5 local storage be migrated to wiki